# Can the historical records in the Bible be considered as accurate/factual records?

Tags: bible

This [question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/547/is-the-bible-considered-a-reliable-historical-resource) was already asked but closed. This is my initial understanding of the Bible, that it consists of the following:

1. Historical "facts", as there are physical evidences such as the [Moabite stone](http://www.accuracyingenesis.com/biblicalarchaeology.html).
2. Religious doctrines, from the Old to the New testament.
3. Prophecies, which of course do not qualify as a historical fact because those predict the future.

Considering only the item 1 I stated above, can the Bible, or the particular records in it, be considered "historical facts"?

My understanding of a "historical record" is that it was *scholarly written*. I am not pertaining to doctrines which may cause debates, but to the historical records only, such as the existence of [Herod the Great](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herod_the_Great).

Comment: Certainly any work can refer to historical facts. But how can you ascertain whether a certain statement is fact or fiction?

Comment: Could you comment where you developed the notion that a historical record is scholarly written? I'm unfamiliar with the notion, and I'm not sure I share that understanding.

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

The bible does contain historical accurate facts that can be verified. However, it contains too much myths and inaccuracies as to be utterly unreliable as the sole source for a historical event.  In fact, the question alludes to this in points (2) and (3).

Comment: I cannot think offhand of any verifiable "historical accurate facts" anwhere in the Bible. Could you give us a few examples and us where they are "verified" outside of the Bible?

Comment: @fdb: Just one example, Jerusalem was a real city under Roman rule around 30 AD.

Comment: Yes, the place names mentioned in the Bible are mostly the names of real places, as are those mentioned in most novels. But I thought we were talking about historical events, "facts".

Comment: @fdb: I fail to see how "Jerusalem is a city" is not a historical fact and how "Jerusalem is under Roman occupation" is not a historical event.  They might be trivial but that's beside the point. ^_~